# Expression values are not inserted into array cell in R

Tags: arrays, r

I have to create n (say 2) no. of matrices of size say `5*5` with different cell value assignment like this :

```
,,1
-1  0  1 -1  0        
 1 -1  0  1 -1
 0  1 -1  0  1
-1  0  1 -1  0
 1 -1  0  1 -1
,,2
0 -1  0  1 -1
1  0  0  1  0
0  0  1  0  1
1  0 -1  0 -1
0 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

For this I have tried following way:

```
r = 5
c = 5
a = 2
m = array(2, dim = c(5,5,2))
for(i in 1:dim(m))
{ for (j in 1:dim(m)) {
  for (k in 1:dim(m)){
  m[i,j,k] = sample(c(-1,1,0),replace =T, 1)

}}}
m
```

and got following error and warnings :

> Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, j, k, value = -1) : subscript out of bounds
>   In addition: Warning messages: 1: In 1:dim(m) : numerical expression
>   has 3 elements: only the first used 2: In 1:dim(m) : numerical
>   expression has 3 elements: only the first used 3: In 1:dim(m) :
>   numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used

But when I tried with matrix function it was giving me correct result, then what's wrong with array.

```
r = 5
c = 5

m = matrix(2,r,c)
for(i in 1:r)
{ for (j in 1:c) {
  m[i,j] = sample(c(0,1,-1),replace =T,prob=c(.33,.33,.34),1)

}}
```

Can anyone please tell me what can be done to resolve this issue.

Comment: sample `r * c * a` elements and then conform them to an array

Comment: @rawr can you please elaborate more

Comment: `d <- c(5,5,2); array(sample(c(-1,1,0), prod(d), TRUE), d)`